# SQL Server 2016 REPORT SERVER REPORTS ARE NOT VIEIWING PROPERLY IN VS 2008 9.0 REPORT VIEWER

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, reportviewer2008, ssrs-2016

We have migrated from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2016, and now reports are not displaying properly in VS 2008 9.0 version of report viewer.

Can anyone tell if we can view reports of SQL Server 2016 in VS 2008 report viewer? As it is not displaying header correctly next and previous button and export button is not working as well.

Thanks

Comment: Reports in 2016 have their own brand new report viewer. Why not upgrade to it?

Comment: Actually it's on client end can't change if i can find any reference that SQL Server 2016  reports is not compatible with  VS 2008 9.0 version of report viewer then it will be good for me to pursue further.

Comment: Could try asking these guys: ssrs-2016-feedback@microsoft.com I had to contact them a couple of times with 2016 reports.

Comment: report works fine by connection development environment to production reports this means there is no compatibility issue. But still embedded resources are not loading. We are on IIS 8.5. Can anyone help how to add handlers mapping in IIS 8.5.